# Installing Windows 8 from DVD (or USB) - Toshiba

Tags: windows-8, bios, uefi, oem, secure-boot

I would like to do a clean install of Windows 8.  I do not want to use the OEM stuff or do a Windows recovery.  I have burned the ISO to a USB drive and when I boot, hit f12, and select USB I get "Checking media... failed"

I tried disabling SecureBoot (f2 to get to UEFI\BIOS options) to no avail.  I am able to boot the USB only when switching from UEFI mode to CSM mode.  I would like to keep UEFI, but simply disable SecureBoot.

Comment: If you attempt to boot to a bootable Windows 8 installation (DVD) disk the process fails? What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the ISO image isn't burned to the USB drive in a way that is compatible with booting from UEFI. Try following the procedure in [Create bootable USB drive for Windows 8 clean install on UEFI](https://superuser.com/q/728834/54568).