# Create bootable USB drive for Windows 8 clean install on UEFI

Tags: windows-8, boot, usb-flash-drive, windows-installation

How do you burn a Windows 8.x ISO image to a USB drive such that it can be clean installed on a PC with [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) enabled? I tried using the [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool), but the target PC didn't see the USB drive as a boot option.

Comment: This question is similar to [No discs found when trying to install Windows 8 with UEFI](http://superuser.com/q/516900/54568), but more general. The related question is targeted to a particular laptop and storage technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open an admin command prompt, and enter the following:

   ```
   diskpart
   list disk
   select disk x (where x is the number of the USB drive from "list disks")
   clean
   create partition primary
   format fs=fat32 quick
   active
   assign
   exit
   ```
2. Mount the ISO image (in running Windows 8, just double click in Windows Explorer).
3. Copy all files and folders from the mounted ISO drive to the USB drive. You can use Windows Explorer, or `xcopy x:\* y:\ /s /e`, replacing `x:` with the ISO drive and `y:` with the USB drive.

Comment: I always use rufus: http://rufus.akeo.ie/