# Windows 10 64 Bit USB Boot Installation Freezing at Windows logo

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, 64-bit, media-creation-tool

***The Problem***

I have a desktop computer running Windows 10 Pro 32 bit. My processor is 64 bit supported so I'd like to upgrade the Windows 10 I'm running, to 64 bit.

I have learnt that the way to do this is by creating a bootable USB using the Windows Media Creation Tool and I have followed all the information step by step at [this link](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-10/upgrade-32-bit-64-bit-version-windows-10/).

After creating the USB successfully, I restarted my computer, pressed F11 which brings up the boot menu and selected to boot from the attached USB created by the tool.

*The computer then begins to attempt booting from the USB and the problem is that the Windows 10 logo appears but with no loading icon (the little loading circles) and the process freezes there. I have waited up to 30 minutes, but no luck.*

***What I've Tried***

1. I've created a bootable USB using another USB pendrive
2. I've created a bootable USB having tried both NTFS and FAT32.
3. I visited my motherboards manufacturer website and downloaded the newest version of the BIOS and successfully flashed the BIOS. (I read somewhere that the problem may have been outdated BIOS software but I don't remember where from).
4. I checked [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1102966/create-windows-10-bootable-installation-usb-drive) out but I didn't try it as our intent is different so I'm not sure if this will work for me.
5. I investigated the problem using Google and YouTube and although many different solutions exist, they all refer to different setups and different boards. One particular video stated that removing the graphics card would correct the problem but it doesn't seem right so I didn't try it.
6. As well as bringing up the boot menu with F11, I also went into the BIOS and explicitly changed the boot order.

***Further Details***

1. My processor supports 64 bit

[image: 64 Bit Support]

2. My motherboard is an MSI X-58 Pro-E 7522
3. The BIOS file used for flashing was A7522IMS.805 which was the last version I needed and was done successfully with no errors.
4. The computer is a custom built one built in 2008.
5. Windows 10 was installed as 32 bit by upgrading from Windows 7. I have only ever done Windows updates when the PC prompted me to do so and have never altered any further settings.
6. If I hold SHIFT and restart, the UEFI menu appears but I have no option to boot from a USB.

There were some articles and videos I came across that claimed to solve this problem but reading the comments and the feedback proved that said "solutions" were in fact opinions and not technical solutions. So I passed on those.

I'd like to start using 64 bit applications which is why I need to start running Windows on 64 bit but I'm not sure what else to check and try here.

Happy to provide any further info if needed.

*Please note that if possible, I prefer not to use third party applications and various other “hacks” to get the job done. I believe that if a USB won’t work with the regular method it may not work with another method. Besides, I am not an advanced user. I am interested in correcting the problem rather than going around it.*

Comment: Download an ISO file via the Media Creation tool _(choose Install on onother PC)_, then use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create the bootable USB _(if receiving a disk access error: `CTRL`+`,` & retry)_.  I also recommend capturing a WIM of the current OS partition prior to re-installing _(you can do so when you boot the Install USB)_, see [Imaging](https://superuser.com/questions/1544510/moving-windows-10-installation-to-another-drive/1544563#1544563) section _(you could actually follow all the steps in that answer to reinstall Windows - at #4, continue with the install and don't cancel)_.

Comment: As already recommended by @JW0914 Rufus is a very good tool to create very reliable  USB installers. By now if you have already successfully installed Windows 10 64 well and good, if not and yet to try any more options I suggest you first check the following. After creating a Windows 10 64 bit USB installer, simply disconnect all HDDs from your computer. Disconnect their SATA power & data cables. Now run the Windows 10 installation from USB.  It should reach a point where it says 'Where do you want to install Windows' Continued..

Comment: Continued..If it still freezes at Windows logo, then you might have a larger problem at hand. Since your hardware is from 2008, Windows 10 64 might have some compatibility issues. If it reaches the point ‘Where do you want to install’ then you have higher chances of getting the 64 bit installer to work after wiping your system partition. Also moreover using suitable tools like CrystalDiskInfo make sure that HDD is in good health before you do anything.

Comment: @patkim I’m downloading the iso now to try it with rufus. Hopefully, it’ll work. Otherwise, disconnecting everything I guess makes sense too.

Comment: If I am using BIOS legacy on the computer and Rufus forces me to select Target System UEFI (non CSM) will the usb still work?

Comment: First use CrystalDiskInfo tool and make sure that HDD is in Good Health. In Rufus under Partition Scheme drop down select MBR, then it will create a Legacy MBR bootable USB installer. UEFI non CSM installer won't boot.

Comment: I went into rufus and pressed alt e which made is uefi and bios compatible. Ill try booting from that usb and see

Comment: Done and completed with Rufus. Windows creation tool must have had a problem. Whoever wants to provide their rufus answer Ill be happy to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the official Windows Media Creation tool.

I created a bootable USB using Rufus and was able to successfully boot from the USB and successfully re-install Windows.

Booting from a USB is a very simple process and when something does not go right - considering the boot USB has been created as per the providers instructions - try creating a boot USB using another method. In my case the official Microsoft tool wouldn't work, but Rufus did. If I had tried Rufus first, I would have saved myself a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to upgrade in place and you cannot do that.

Start your system as is (I assume it starts), update BIOS to whatever is the newest version and all other drivers.  Use the Manufacturer's driver update application to do this.

Now back up all your data, email, favorites and so on. Make sure you have everything. If you have a file of software keys make sure you get that. Be certain about your backup because converting to 64-bit is like starting over (like starting over with a new drive)

Now format the drive and install Windows 10 64-bit fresh.

Use the ISO from the Microsoft Media Creation Link and make a bootable USB from it. That will allow you to install Windows 10 64-bit. Licensing will be OK (from the Licensing Server)

Install the newest version of all your applications.

Restore your data and you are all done.

Comment: How would I install Windows 10? Wouldn’t that be with usb too?

Comment: You can use use the ISO from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.  I adjusted my answer.

Comment: Are you sure that using a bootable ISO usb will work? If it doesn’t I won’t be able to get Windows back on whereas now at least I have 32 bit running for other non 64 bit tasks. I guess I’ll try this only as a last resort.

Comment: It should work. I used the same to convert a hard drive to an SSD drive on my desktop computer. You need to be certain about securely backing up your stuff, because converting to 64-bit is like starting over - the same as replacing a disk.

Comment: @NikosV If you are currently running Windows from an HDD, now could be a good time to change to an SSD. You will get to keep the HDD as an *extra* backup disk.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Makes sense but SSDs are smaller in size so I’ll have to come back to that and see. SSDs are definitely worth it though.

Comment: A 500 GB SSD should be fine for most needs. I have larger ones to support multiple virtual machines, but 500 GB is fine for general use. Get a good drive with good warranty (Samsung for example)